# Mysql query to fetch under warranty products

Tags: php, mysql

```
 My table structure is as:

 ID(int) , product_name(varchar) , size(int) , manufacturing_date(date) , warranty_duration(int)
```

I want to make a query which fetch the products which are under warranty. warranty duration is provided in years.

I hope my question is clear !

Comment: Please let us know what have tried.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: i fetch all the products and after that filter under warranty products which is not optimized solution and takes lots of time i want to filter it at DB end.

Comment: Little bit more information would be very helpfull. I am assuming the manufacturing date is the starting of the warranty? If that is true you have to go through the whole table and compare today's date with the manufacturing date and the warranty duration.

Comment: @Ullas please let me know what is the confusion?

Comment: @OSDM  **manufacturing date is the starting of the warranty** this is true and i know to compare today's date with manufacturing date but tell me how to compare it with warranty duration?

Comment: Atleast show what script you've tried so far, this is like asking other people to answer an assignment given to you. IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that current date to check warranty like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name
 WHERE NOW() > manufacturing_date 
   AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(manufacturing_date, INTERVAL warranty_duration YEAR)
```

Comment: Thanks :) 

also can you tell me how to find time left in warranty expire?

Answer (score 0):

this query should help you.

```
 select * from 'table name' where current date > manufacturing_date 
 and current date < DATE_ADD(manufacturing_date, INTERVAL warranty_duration YEAR)
```